# SQL Mirroring or Failover Clustering VS Azure built in infrastructure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, high-availability

I read in a few places that SQL Azure data is automatically replicated and the Azure platform provides redundant copies of the data, Therefore SQL Server high availability features such as database mirroring and failover cluster aren't needed.

Has anyone got a chance to investigate deeper into this? Are all those availability enhancements really not needed in Azure? Thanks!

To clarify, I'm talking about SQL as a service and not a VM hosted SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Database service (database-as-a-service) is a multi-tenant database service, and your databases are triple-replicated within the data center, providing *durable* storage. The service itself, being large-scale, provides high availability (since there are many VMs running the service itself, along with replicated data). Nothing is needed in terms of mirroring or failover clusters. Having said that: If, say, your particular database became unavailable for a period of time, you'll need to consider how you'll handle that situation (perhaps sync'ing to another SQL Database, maybe even in another data center).

If you go with SQL Database (DBaaS), you'll still need to work out your [backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx) strategy, and possibly syncing with another DC (or on-premises database server) for DR purposes.

More info on SQL Database fault tolerance is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852669.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question reffered to the hosted solution. We don't need the ommited functionality...

Comment: Right - and I specifically referenced that, specifically the need for Always On configuration for HA. I'll edit for storage durability though.

Comment: Look, I only asked about non VM option. Your answer is packed with information about VM, it's pretty confusing... In addition to that, the ommited functionality was not a part of the question and it really is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok. Updated with just sql db. Hopefully it's of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much much clearer :) When you say Sync, do you mean live sync or would a backup restore be enough? Thing is that Live Sync on DBaas is quite awful as it adds tons on junk (Triggers, Constraints, whatever) to the schema and makes it really hard to manage dev / prod versions when deploying database schema changes...

Answer (score 0):

Your desired detail is probably contained in this MSDN article of Business Continuity and Azure SQL Database (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh852669.aspx).  At the most basic level Azure SQL Database will keep three replicas of your database - one primary and two secondary.

While this helps with BCP / DR scenarios you may also wish to investigate ways to backup your database so you have point-in-time restore capabilities.  More information on backup / restore can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx

Comment: Both of these links were already provided by @David Kakogon. Thanks anyway.